# Why is it not possible to exchange the position of array name and index in swift like C (a[i] == i[a])?

Tags: c, arrays, swift

**The C Code**:-

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int a[5]={33,19,13,25,51};
   int t1 = a[4];
   int t2 = 4[a];         // surprise here
   printf("%d\n", t1);
   printf("%d", t2);
}
```

> prints same output:- 51   51

But In swift why is it not possible to change the position of Array name and its index?`

Comment: Because they're different languages, right?

Comment: Why does in English IS mean IS not EGG? Same kind of question.

Comment: I think `// surprise here` is the answer to your question.

Answer (score 8):

**The reason**: arrays are not first-class data types in C, but in other languages they are.

Because C doesn't support arrays as full native types, array access devolves into *pointer math*, so `arr[ix]` is defined by the language to be `*(arr + ix)`, which is the same as `*(ix + arr)` plus the curious `ix[arr]` as all being *exactly* equivalent.

It's not *intended* that you do Stupid C Tricks like `47[buffer]` but it's allowed.

Other languages that treat arrays as first-class data types don't need to define them in terms of pointer math so can support them natively and fully, and there would be no reason to support this odd artifact.

In C, this is a great way to fool your friends by asking them: what is printed?

```c
// what is printed?
#include <stdio.h>

int a[] = { 4, 2, 0, 1, 3 };

int main()
{       
    int i = 1[a][a][a][a];  // HUH?

    printf("i = %d\n", i);

    return 0;
}
```

This is completely legal and well-defined by the language, but echoing the sentiments of one of my threadmates, Father forgive me, for I have sinned. :-)

Answer (score 6):

As Steve Friedl said, it's just a coincidental side effect of the definition of `array[i]` being equivalent to `*(arr + i)`. Though not necessarily a bug, it isn't really a feature, because you don't really get anything out of having it..

Since there's no reason to support this, most languages don't bother implementing it.

Swift has extensions, so you *could* implement this syntax, but dear god, don't do this.

```
extension Int {
    subscript<T>(array: [T]) -> T {
        return array[self]
    }
}

let a = [33, 19, 13, 25, 51]
print(a[4]) // => 51
print(4[a]) // => 51
```

Father forgive me, for I have sinned.